# Is it possible to have a Map with lambda values Map<key, function>?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm having a collection of classes generated for me **so I can't modify** these classes to add polymorphistic behavior. Unfortunately, I need to have some different behavior based on the type in their inheritance.

One solution is to write decorators for all these objects so I can augment this objects with DDD-like behavior or use some visitor pattern. However, I thought of another simpler way to execute some different behavior based on the type.

Here's what I was thinking of and in itself an interesting exercise into what is possible with Lambda's in Java:

```
Map<Class, SomeLambdaFunction<String>> typeMap = ImmutableMap.<Class, SomeLambdaFunction<String>>builder()
    .put(SubClassA.class, () -> someCondition() ? "valueA" : "valueB")
    .put(SubClassB.class, () -> aStringMethod() + anotherStringMethod())
    .build();
```

I would like to 'lookup' a piece of behavior this way. Since I don't expect this collection of generated classes to change anymore (it's old legacy stuff), I'm not worried about violating the [Open / Closed Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by `Lambda<String>`?  `Lambda` is not a type in the Java language, nor is it defined in the Java standard library.  There is no such thing as a "lambda" at run-time.  At least, there's no such thing if *you* did not define it.

A lambda *expression* is just a way of creating a new object.  You can't use it to create *any* object of course, but you can use it to create an object that belongs to an anonymous class that implements some particular *functional interface*. But still, the result of a lambda is not essentially different from all of the other kinds of object.  It's *just* an object.

So, all you really are asking is, "Is it possible to create a map that maps keys of type `Class` to values of some other type?"

Yes.  That's possible.

More specifically, what you are asking for is a `Map<Class, Foobar>` where `Foobar` is the name of the functional interface type that your lambdas all implement.

---

Instead of writing `SomeLambdaFunction<String>`, I think your example would make more sense if you wrote it like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CustomBehavior {
    String doCustomThing();
}

Map<Class, CustomBehavior> typeMap =
    ImmutableMap.<Class, CustomBehavior>builder()
        .put(SubClassA.class, () -> someCondition() ? "valueA" : "valueB")
        .put(SubClassB.class, () -> aStringMethod() + anotherStringMethod())
        .build();
```

Those lambda expressions don't return `String` objects; They return `CustomBehavior` objects.  The code below does exactly the same thing as the code above, except it does it with named classess instead of with anonymous classes.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CustomBehavior {
    String doCustomThing();
}

class CustomBehaviorA implements CustomBehavior {
    public String doCustomThing() {
        return someCondition() ? "valueA" : "valueB";
    }
}

class CustomBehaviorB implements CustomBehavior {
    public String doCustomThing() {
        return aStringMethod() + anotherStringMethod();
    }
}

Map<Class, CustomBehavior> typeMap =
    ImmutableMap.<Class, CustomBehavior>builder()
        .put(SubClassA.class, new CustomBehaviorA())
        .put(SubClassB.class, new CustomBehaviorB())
        .build();
```

Comment: This is the answer - there is no such thing as a "lambda" - it's just shorthand for implementing an SMI.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, but you will have to use an interface as the value type, which you then implement using a lambda definition.

Some common interfaces availale are [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) or [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). *Runnable* doesn't have a return value and *Callable* throws `Exception` forcing you to catch it, *Function* needs an argument. *Supplier* remains a good candidate.

Here's an example with Supplier and sub class based keys:

```
public String getLambdaValueForKey(String key) {
    final Map<Class<? extends YourBaseClass>, Supplier<String>> lambdaMap = ImmutableMap.<Class<? extends YourBaseClass>, Supplier<String>>builder()
        .put(SubclassA.class, () -> someCondition() ? "valueA" : "valueB")
        .put(SubclassB.class, () -> aStringMethod() + anotherStringMethod())
        .build();
    return lambdaMap.get(key).get(); // the 2nd get is Supplier's .get()
}
```

However, as mentioned here in the comments, in general you're better with explicitly `instanceof` checks. Only in very specific case (like the fixed generated classes that don't change due to legacy) this would work in the long-term.

Comment: This example is marginally better in that it actually uses a lambda rather than a static `String`. However, it is awful in that it's basically a less robust `instanceof` (doesn't deal with inheritance). If you need to use this, you need to rethink your application logic. This is worse than answers that suggest using `instanceof` as a solution to the "how do I do different things depending on the `class`?' questions.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I would agree in general, but this is a very specific situation however where the generated structure is fixed forever (old legacy code). I updated the answer to reflect this.